mongoDB exception opening socket with BIRT 4.8 (MongoDb, BIRT)
NOTE: this is a solution:
If you are trying to run BIRT innoventsolutions dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.innoventsolutions.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>

But you've got this runtime error:

[localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017%0d%0a%0d%0acom.mongodb.mongosocketopenexception: exception opening socket.

If you are not using mongoDb in your application. You can simply exclude it from the dependency as shown below:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.innoventsolutions.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.innoventsolutions.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb_3.2.2.v20170222-2110</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


You can separate the solution from the question statement itself in the self Q&A style. This is actually encouraged and will make your solution more clear to future readers
